# Trouble With My Image Scraper

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, lxml

I am trying to make an image scraper and was wondering if anyone can help with the below example:

```
page = requests.get('www.example.com/image1')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

pic = tree.xpath(Copied XPath)

print pic[0].attrib['src']
```

now in the 'page' I have the url of the image in this case 'www.example.com/image1'.  I want to know if it is possible to loop this process if I have a list of image names e.g image 2, image 3, image 4 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
list_of_image_names = ['image1', 'image2', 'image3']

for image_name in list_of_image_names:
    page = requests.get('www.example.com/' + image_name)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

    pic = tree.xpath(Copied XPath)

    print pic[0].attrib['src']
```

Comment: No problem. Remember that lists are iterable in python so there is no need to write `for` loop like @The2ndSon did - `for picture in range(len(pictureList)):` - it's much more complex than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code that you posted above is functional, you can duplicate that same functionality in some sort of loop.  Here is an example of how this would work.

```
def picLooper():
    pictureList = ['image1','image2', 'image3'] # list of image names
    pictureURL = dict() # dictionary to hold URL for images
    for picture in range(len(pictureList)):
        page = requests.get('www.example.com/' + pictureList[picture])
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

        pic = tree.xpath(Copied XPath)
        pictureURL[image] = pic
```

It may be worth noting that this implementation assumes that you have knowledge of the image names that you want to grab.  Hope this helps as a starting point! :D

Comment: I have a list of image names (over 7000) in a csv.  This is going to be defined as a function

Comment: Okay, so then pictureList is something that you are able to generate beforehand?  Sounds like you got it figured out.